# Can I get the hour that a TimeSpan begins?

Tags: c#, timespan

I'm have to get the initial and the last hour of a TimeSpan variable. Is it possible to obtain? I haven't found anything talking about this.

Comment: a timespan is a measure of time, not when it starts.  unless im wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand the purpose of `TimeSpan`.

It does not represent "From a specific time to a specific time".

It represents a length of time, like "5 minutes" or "6 hours".

To represent "a specific time to a specific time" you need to use two `DateTime` objects: one for the start time, and one for the end time.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. The user case specified that I need to use the TimeSpan that the other company sent me to work with the information. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A `TimeSpan` is a measure of time, how long some event took. Like how long did it take to run a race. How long do you boil pasta for. At what interval do you want an event to execute. You could not find the initial hour and last hour of any of those.

What *is* possible is to apply a `TimeSpan` instance to a `DateTime` instance. The initial `DateTime` being when the event *started* and the resulting `DateTime` when the event *ended*. Only looking at hour though, as you mention in your question, could lead to bad results if the start and end occur on different days.

Example:

```
TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0); // 3 hours
DateTime start = new DateTime(2017, 5, 12, 16, 25, 0); // starts on
DateTime end = start.Add(duration); // ends 3 hours from start
```